# Regex structure to identify name(s) before key word

Tags: regex

I am trying to write an expression to identify station locations within a sentence in knowledge studio (IBM Watson).

At the moment I have

```
[^a-z][^\s]*(.*?)\s+station|Station
```

but it is causing me some problems:
1. It is extracting the whole line rather than just the station (e.g. "Please meet at Angel Station" is extracted rather than just "Angel Station").
2. I can't seem to find how to write an exception within an expression.  For example, I would usually want to find all words before station that are not lower case (uppercase, titlecase or numerical), but if it is and then I want it to continue identifying words (e.g. Highbury and Islington Station, not just select Islington station).

Please advise on what I am doing wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably, [`\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?:\s+(?:and|[A-Z][A-Za-z]*))*\s+[Ss]tation`](https://regex101.com/r/yjlDno/1) will help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would suggest anything between the capital letter and `tation` since names may have other connectives besides "and".

Comment: @NetMage What did you have in mind here? I see your point (e.g. Staines upon Thames), but can’t think of a catch-all that wouldn’t cause other problems (e.g. not select ‘Meet Fiona at Angel Station’. I am new to Regex so please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can see that this works in the test environment and is exactly the solution I am looking for, but for some reason, it then does not work in Knowledge Studio.  I've created the associated class and entity.

Comment: Then, most probably it is not supporting regex, or you are using it incorrectly. BTW, it "does not work"  is not helpful feedback. You only asked for a regex, but you have other problem, as far as I can see.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It supports Regex & I have other rules (e.g. ([A-Z][^\s]*) to identify titlecase words (initial starting point for this rule), identifying who the letter is addressed to (words after Dear) and these are working. However, when I use the above on the sample text (there are three sample texts with 5 station mentions) it only identifies one and then only partially.  In a sentence 'Please meet at Truman's Wonderfully Big TVR ET Green Station" it is picking up 'Big TVR ET Green Station', in the other examples such as 'Oak Lane Station' it is not identifying anything but does in test

Comment: That sounds like your tool doesn't support multiple matching and only searches for a match once, correct? You should consult your tool documentation to learn if you can do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I think is IBM Watson Knowledge Studio specific - you have to define a specific number of word tokens outside of the regex structure - by default this is limited to 5 so needed to be increased to pick up all of the words correctly.  I increased this to 10 which work fine for my purpose.

In terms of then the correct structure the below worked:

```
\b[A-Z][A-Za-z']*(?:\s+(?:and|[A-Z][A-Za-z']*))*\s+[Ss]tation
```

Note - I needed to include the ' symbol to ensure all stations were picked up (e.g. King's Cross Station).

Oak Lane Station is still not selecting, but this seems to be a bug rather than an issue with the Regex so have reported it to the IBM Watson team.